# How to put values from one table to another WHERE column1 of table1 = column2 of table2?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table1  and table 2 both have two columns

> id
>
> score

I want a query for MySQL 5.5 that allows me to update `score` of my `table2` where ever `id` of `table1` = `id` of `table2` where `id` = 1.

In other words,I want a sql where to make the score of a specific id same in both the tables when the query runs in whatever row occure,the score field in that row must be the same but not all the ids,just the id which is = 1.

Comment: Please "un-tag" "Sql Server"....on your question.

Comment: Please do a little research next time, this question has been asked and answered many many times.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
UPDATE table2 t2
SET score = (SELECT score from table1 WHERE id = 1)
WHERE id = 1
```